# Occasional SEGFAULT in my c++ code with flatbuffers

Tags: c++, c++11, flatbuffers

I'm working on my C++ project with flatbuffers. I started with google's online example and wrote a google test. However, this test sometimes failed with SEGFAULT.

Following are the code snippets.

```cpp
// moster.fbs

namespace MyGame.Sample;

enum Color:byte { Red = 0, Green, Blue = 2 }

union Equipment { Weapon } // Optionally add more tables.

struct Vec3 {
  x:float;
  y:float;
  z:float;
}

table Monster {
  pos:Vec3; // Struct.
  mana:short = 150;
  hp:short = 100;
  name:string;
  friendly:bool = false (deprecated);
  inventory:[ubyte];  // Vector of scalars.
  color:Color = Blue; // Enum.
  weapons:[Weapon];   // Vector of tables.
  equipped:Equipment; // Union.
  path:[Vec3];        // Vector of structs.
}

table Weapon {
  name:string;
  damage:short;
}

root_type Monster;
```

```cpp
// test.cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "monster_generated.h"

using namespace MyGame::Sample;

void WriteMonsterToFile(const std::string& filename)
{
  // Build up a serialized buffer algorithmically:
  flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder;

  // First, lets serialize some weapons for the Monster: A 'sword' and an 'axe'.
  auto weapon_one_name = builder.CreateString("Sword");
  short weapon_one_damage = 3;

  auto weapon_two_name = builder.CreateString("Axe");
  short weapon_two_damage = 5;

  // Use the `CreateWeapon` shortcut to create Weapons with all fields set.
  auto sword = CreateWeapon(builder, weapon_one_name, weapon_one_damage);
  auto axe = CreateWeapon(builder, weapon_two_name, weapon_two_damage);

  // Create a FlatBuffer's `vector` from the `std::vector`.
  std::vector<flatbuffers::Offset<Weapon>> weapons_vector;
  weapons_vector.push_back(sword);
  weapons_vector.push_back(axe);
  auto weapons = builder.CreateVector(weapons_vector);

  // Second, serialize the rest of the objects needed by the Monster.
  auto position = Vec3(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f);

  auto name = builder.CreateString("MyMonster");

  unsigned char inv_data[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
  auto inventory = builder.CreateVector(inv_data, 10);

  // Shortcut for creating monster with all fields set:
  auto orc = CreateMonster(builder, &position, 150, 80, name, inventory,
                           Color_Red, weapons, Equipment_Weapon, axe.Union());

  builder.Finish(orc);  // Serialize the root of the object.

  // We now have a FlatBuffer we can store on disk or send over a network.
  std::ofstream outfile(filename, std::ios::binary);
  outfile.write((char*)builder.GetBufferPointer(), builder.GetSize());
  outfile.flush();
  outfile.close();
}

TEST(FlatbuffersTest, Monster)
{
  WriteMonsterToFile("monster.bin");

  // ** file/network code goes here :) **
  std::ifstream infile;
  infile.open("monster.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
  infile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
  int length = infile.tellg();
  infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  char* data = new char[length];
  infile.read(data, length);
  infile.close();

  // Get access to the root:
  auto monster = GetMonster(data);
  delete[] data;

  // Get and test some scalar types from the FlatBuffer.
  EXPECT_EQ(monster->hp(), 80);
  EXPECT_EQ(monster->mana(), 150);
  EXPECT_EQ(monster->name()->str(), "MyMonster");

  // Get and test a field of the FlatBuffer's `struct`.
  auto pos = monster->pos();
  EXPECT_EQ(pos->z(), 3.0f);

  // Get a test an element from the `inventory` FlatBuffer's `vector`.
  auto inv = monster->inventory();
  EXPECT_EQ(inv->Get(9), 9);

  // Get and test the `weapons` FlatBuffers's `vector`.
  std::string expected_weapon_names[] = {"Sword", "Axe"};
  short expected_weapon_damages[] = {3, 5};
  auto weps = monster->weapons();
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < weps->size(); i++) {
    EXPECT_EQ(weps->Get(i)->name()->str(), expected_weapon_names[i]);
    EXPECT_EQ(weps->Get(i)->damage(), expected_weapon_damages[i]);
  }

  // Get and test the `Equipment` union (`equipped` field).
  EXPECT_EQ(monster->equipped_type(), Equipment_Weapon);
  auto equipped = static_cast<const Weapon*>(monster->equipped());
  EXPECT_EQ(equipped->name()->str(), "Axe");
  EXPECT_EQ(equipped->damage(), 5);
}
```

test output:

```bash
$ ctest --rerun-failed --output-on-failure
Test project /root/cpcos/build_linux64
    Start 3: FlatbuffersTest.Monster
1/1 Test #3: FlatbuffersTest.Monster ..........***Exception: SegFault  0.01 sec
Running main() from /home/conan/w/BuildSingleReference/.conan/data/gtest/1.11.0/_/_/build/7320405f83ec32d8556b524cdda87ee295bb7b84/source_subfolder/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
Note: Google Test filter = FlatbuffersTest.Monster
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from FlatbuffersTest
[ RUN      ] FlatbuffersTest.Monster
/root/cpcos/tests/flatbuffers_gtest.cpp:71: Failure
Expected equality of these values:
  monster->hp()
    Which is: 100
  80


0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.04 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          3 - FlatbuffersTest.Monster (SEGFAULT)
Errors while running CTest
```

I compiled the code and ran it many times, strangely, it sometimes PASS while sometimes failed with SEGFAULT.

What did I do wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have access to valgrind use it.

Comment: ***it sometimes PASS while sometimes failed with SEGFAULT*** Sounds like the code has some undefined behavior.

Comment: `auto monster = GetMonster(data);` Maybe the bug is in `GetMonster()`

Comment: Your asking people online to debug your code for you, but you haven't even run it under GDB or whatever to find out where exactly it segfaults and with what values?

Comment: Oh and `delete[] data;` is definitely a problem. If you read the docs on FlatBuffers, you'll find that it accesses your data "in place" meaning, `monster` is a reference to objects encoded in `data`.

Comment: @Aardappel, thank you. You're exactly right about ```delete[] data``` things. Thank you for saving my day.